# Make an L shaped object have round corners

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

How can I modify an L shaped object so it will have round corners? It is one of the basic shapes you can choose in the menu.

[image]

I know I can do it with a "regular" shape:

[image]

I want my L shape to look something like this (ignore the person):

[image]

I tried editing corners, but it doesn't seem to work. I searched other answers, but couldn't find an answer for this.

I am using Microsoft Office 2019 Professional Plus (couldn't find a fitting tag, please tag if possible)

Comment: Overlay two rectangles with rounded corners (and link them, if in Vizio).

Comment: I tried this but the inner angle is still not round @DrMoishePippik

Comment: I suggest you insert a rectangle with rounded corners, choose it, right-click > Edit points > select one line to right click > Add Point, then adjust the shape.

Comment: @Emily I tried this, but it doesn't scale when I change the size of the shape...

Answer (score 2):

I solved it:

Created two rectangles and placed them one atop the other:
[two rectangles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOd0N.png)

I created two squares, and placed them one atop the other:
[two squares](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2BkM.png)

Now I substracted the two squares: [subtracted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mLvZx.png)

Placed the new piece so its borders match the two rectangles: [after matching](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IsFkQ.png)

And for last I selected all the shapes and merged them: [merged](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1B4X.png)

Tada!